# SignalR IOS push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, signalr

I have a project currently running on SignalR to send push notifications to my website, and I would now want it to send to iOS devices, but I can't find any relevant resources. Can someone provide me some basic code on sending push notifications to IOS device using SignalR ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have SignalR set up on your web service pushing notifications to your web site, then you just need to create a connection to the SignalR service and subscribe to the notifications from youu iOS device.  I have used [SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) to handle push notifications to native iOS apps in the past and it works quite well.  Here's the simple code to use to set up the connection:

```
SRConnection *connection = [SRConnection connectionWithURL:@"http://localhost/mysite/echo"];
connection.received = ^(NSString * data) {
    NSLog(data);
};
connection.started =  ^{
    [connection send:@"hello world"];
};
[connection start];
```